# Gate driver circuit design for High-side and Low-side

Tags: switches, dc-dc-converter, high-side, low-side

I am designing integrated DC-DC converter with multiple output. As I am new to Analog design, I am trying to figure out what type of circuit topology is to be used for high-side and low-side switches. High-side is a pmos and lowside is a nmos switch. I am using 22nm technology with typical Li-ion battery input voltage with 1.8V operation for switches. Can anyone help me what type of topology to use?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  Do you have a PDK from which you can select an appropriate PMOS and NMOS device?  Without more information you probably won't get a good answer here.

Comment: @JohnD I have PDK to work on the technology. 22nm technology. Though for the high-side and low-side I will try with LDMOS. I am just not sure which topology to use from the PWM output to the LDMOS for driving the gate. What I mean, I am looking for gate driver circuit. Googling give me mostly to use gate driver ic to use which is not my intention. I want to start with common gate driver topology to start with.

Comment: I see.  Given your gate capacitance and total gate charge (of the LDMOS), the max switching frequency of your converter, and your desired switching times you can calculate the peak current required from the driver.  Then design a complementary driver that's capable of supplying the peak current in the time required.

Comment: @JohnD I figured my peak current required and switching frequency as well. I also sized preliminarily my LDMOS with current requirement. I need to drive the mosfet now from digital PWM. So I have to drive the design a circuit between the DPWM and the pmos and as well as nmos and other switches. Now for PMOS I selected the lowest voltage of Li-ion battery 2.5V (guess) and input pwm voltage would be 1.8V during its ON-duty cycle. Did you mean the complementary driver circuit by using inverters side by side like delay driver?

Comment: You can see a conventional approach and a new technique in this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Conventional-gate-drive-circuit-with-power-MOSFET-and-its-associated-parasitics_fig1_3281440

Comment: @JohnD thanks a lot. I am reading the paper.